# Cutting two string elements

Tags: php, string, subst

Alright so I am basically trying to cut 2 parts of a string

```
$string = "505 Space X 24";
```

Now what I am trying to do is basically cut everything besides Space X

So the output would be

```
"Space X"
```

Now, I dont know what will be the first number or the last one (the entire thing is dynamic) but it will always be

```
INT STRING INT
```

I tried using substr but I am not sure how to cut 2 parts of it.

I want to basically show only the string

EDIT: More info, I have to cut first 3 characters and last 3 characters from the string.

Comment: Provide few more examples as well to get clear.

Comment: what is `"Space X"`? is it always static or could it be `"Space XXX1"`?

Comment: Nope not always static. It will display the row name from SQL. Basically I have to cut first 3 characters and last 3 characters from the entire string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try to transform the string to an array, and get everythign but the first and last elements as they are numbers:

```
$string = "505 Space X 24";

$exploded = explode(' ', $string); // ['505', 'Space', 'X', '24']
$str_elements = array_slice($exploded, 1, -1); // ['Space', 'X']
$str = implode($str_elements, ' '); // 'Space X'
var_dump($str);
```

Comment: Yep thats the one! Thanks mate! So basically array_slice cuts the first and last element? Nice one, didnt think of it! :)

Comment: array_slice will return an array starting at a specific offset, for a specific length. If you specify a negative value for it, it will start from the end.

Comment: Feel free to accept the answer if it is what you want :)

Comment: Woah nice one mate! I will accept the answer as soon as I can (should be in 3 minutes)